# Buying checks from places besides your bank? How does it work?

Tags: banking, check

I just opened a new account at Bank of America. The checks they sell aren't cheap and I heard that you can buy checks elsewhere. Does this mean that I can just buy a packet of blanket check and just fill in my account and routing number?

I've never done something like this before so I just want to make sure.

Also, I'm not sure if this is allowed, but if so, could I get a recommendation for places to buy cheap checks?

Thanks

Comment: Some check printing services offer a "first time customer" discount deal to encourage you to try them out. Shop around... Note to that many banks provide the checks free if you maintain a high enough balance, again as a marketing tool.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No, you give them your account and routing number, and they pre-print it. It has to be printed with a special MICR ink and with a special font. You can buy a cartridge of such ink for your printer and print it yourself on a bunch of stock check paper, but it won't be any cheaper.

[More information about the MICR line on a check](http://www.elfring.com/what.htm):

> The bottom line on all checks printed and used in North America (and many other countries worldwide)  is printed using a special font called MICR (short for Magnetic Ink Character Recognition). MICR is usually pronounced My-ker. The bottom line on a check must always be printed in the MICR typeface using a special magnetic ink.
>
> [image: MICR line on a check]
>
> The MICR line on a check allows the check information to be automatically read by inexpensive machines. This is the only way that huge numbers of checks can be processed each day.
>
> MICR line printing needs to be accurate to better than 1 part in 1,000! Your magnetic toner must stay on the paper under adverse conditions and have a specific signal strength.

You can look at prices at Walmart, Costco or Vistaprint, they're all pretty cheap.

Comment: And the checks can be plain, just colored paper, or have nearly any kind of design you wish.